# how to count elements in a list and put them in a dictionary

Tags: python

Hi im a phyton newbee in a spot of bother i am taking a file from the internet reading it and cleaning it up by splitting on the new line then on the comma and the output is thousands of rows which look like this:

```
 [59, 'Self-emp-inc', 'none', 'none', 10, 'Married-civ-spouse',
'Craft-repair', 'Husband', 'White', 'Male', 0, 0, 50, 'none', '>50K']
```

what i am trying to do then is loop through line count each attribute and depending on whether the last element is either `>50K` or `<=50K`i want to put it in either age_over_dict or age_under_dict so at the end i should have for each attribute `age_over_dict{59:79,Self-emp-inc:56}` so for the ammount of people who are 59 and earn >50K is 79 and so on. I cant seem to get this part working any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance. This is the code i have at the moment

```
    def trainClassifier(f):
        age_over = {}
        age_under = {}
        count = 0
        count_over = 0
        count_under = 0
        for row in f:
        row = row.split(", ")
        count +=1
        if row[-1]in f == " >50K":
            if row[0] in f == age_over:
                age_over +=1
                count_over+=1
            else:
                age_over = age_over + 1
                count_over+=1
        print(age_over,count_over,count)

        return age_over
```

Comment: If and else branches do the same thing.

Comment: Do you know what exactly `row[-1] in f == " >50K"` does?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are asking:

```
def trainClassifier(f):
    count = 0
    count_over = 0
    count_under = 0

    age_over  = {}
    age_under = {}
    for line in f:
        row = [ x.strip() for x in line.split(",") ]
        print row
        count +=1
        if int(row[0]) > 50:
            dest_dict = age_over
        else:
            dest_dict = age_under

        for attr in row:
            if attr not in dest_dict:
                dest_dict[attr] = 1
            else:
                dest_dict[attr] += 1

    return age_over,age_under
```

However, notice that duplicated attributes would be counted multiple times for each record in the csv. Not sure that is the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` from `collections` creates histograms from iterables.

```
from collections import Counter
```

First you need to filter for the information you want to count on. In your case, age, the first element, and income, the last element. I grab these elements in the list comprehension, and pass the result to Counter for the counts of each age, income pair.

```
Counter([(i[0],i[-1]) for i in f])
```

Here's an example, a list of lists with [age, nonesense, income]:

```
>>> a
[[30, 1, '>50'], [59, 2, '<50'], [30, 3, '>50']]
```

The intermediate step of filtering on just the data we need:

```
>>> b = [(i[0], i[-1]) for i in a]
>>> b
[(30, '>50'), (59, '<50'), (30, '>50')]
```

and the result of building the counter:

```
>>> c = Counter(b)
>>> c
Counter({(30, '>50'): 2, (59, '<50'): 1})
```

From here, if you wanted to know the number of people who are 30 and make greater than 50k, you can use `c` like a dictionary:

```
>>> c[30,'>50']
2
```